# Using Lucene QueryAPI to access SQL

Tags: sql, lucene

Can you advise on whether I can use just the Query functionality from Lucene to generate SQL queries? Something like an SQLQueryBuilder?

I have a massive SQL database of logs from a webserver cluster containing the original request and response strings plus some other useful/less bits and bobs. What I need to do is analyse the parameters in the original request and compare with the generated responses, looking at ratios, volatility, variability, consistency etc.

This question does not relate to the analysis stage, but only the retrieval of data from database which matches the parameters I'm interested in. So, I could just do this in good old sql queries, manually building the exact queries I need on a case-by-case basis. But that's kinda lame; I reckon we can be a bit smarter than that. Particularly as I can already see large numbers of similar but subtly different queries being useful. And as I'm hoping that I can expose a single search box via a web interface to non-technical end-users, adding sql queries seems like a bad idea... and a recipe for permanent maintenance requests (and can I be the first to say, er no thanks!).

In an ideal world I expose a search form, with the option to write simple queries like

```
request:"someAttribute=\"someValue\"" AND response="some hoped for result" AND daterange:30
```

which would then hopefully find all instances of requests which contain someAttribute="someValue" over the last 30 days. The results will then be put through standard statistical analyses on the given response text and printed out on-screen. At least, that's the idea.

Much of the actual logic to determine how to handle custom field definitions or special words I'll need to write myself, and that's ok. And NB, my non-technical end users are familiar enough with xml that they can handle a bit of attr="value" syntax, at least for the first iteration of the tool :D

In summary, I want to:
1) allow users to use google-like search syntax (e.g. via Lucene's QueryAPI) to specify text to match in the logs
2) allow a layer to manipulate the query based on special words or fields (e.g. this layer could be during a Java object phase)
3) convert the final query into an sql query appropriate for my database schema
4) query the database and spit back the resultset for statistical analysis
5) pretty-print on website:)

Am I completely barking up the wrong tree? It looks like it should be possible, but I can't seem to find much on it. I've been googling for a bit on this, for example trying "Lucene SQLQueryBuilder" as a possible start but didn't really find much by way of a lead.

So, my questions are:

- Has anyone tried using Lucene's QueryAPI like this before? Did it work? Any gotchas?
- Are there better query api libraries out there?

Examples, finished discussions and open-source implementations would be most helpful.

Many thanks.

NB: I don't think I want Lucene's search capabilities as such, as I'm only ever looking for exact matches. I just need a query layer on top of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene and SQL have very little in common as they're using totally different syntax (as HefferWolf mentioned) and different underlying data models. As you said yourself, I'm afraid you're barking the wrong tree.

There are however attempts, such as [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) to bridge this gap. These are interesting experiments as such, but I would be very careful to use any of that code in production.

You could possibly use Full Text Search features available in some SQL databases, or reindex all data in Lucene and use it without database.

Comment: We use hibernate-search in production quite successfully, even a mix of using lucene directly for search and using hibernate-search just for indexing works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can reuse any code from lucene for this. Lucene does an internal rewrite of such queries but into a syntax which wouldn't be of much help for SQL I think.

```
name: Phil AND lastname: Miller AND NOT age: 26
```

would be rewritten to

```
+name Phil +lastname: Miller -age: 26
```

So I think you would have to write your on transition into a SQL Query syntax.

But maybe you can use Lucene as such for this. Have a look into [hibernate-search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) which is quite handy to easily create a lucene index of a sql table.

Comment: I thought Lucene created a java object tree to represent the query? I'm assuming that would come _after_ the rewrite you're mentioning? I'm hoping that someone might be familiar with interacting with these objects.

I looked at the hibernate search stuff; does that even work if the underlying sql structure has nothing to do with hibernate?

Comment: no hibernate-search only works if you use hibernate for this.